# Trying to access php symfony docker container on localhost

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose, dockerfile

as you can see below I have this docker compose file
after building the containers I went inside the bash of symfony-container and installed symfony 4.4
now I am trying to connect to http://localhost:9000 but I cannot access it whatsoever
any ideas ? is it possible to access it without using nginx as service ?
I am using Ubuntu

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  playing:


services:

  #symfony
  symfony-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./config/symfony/Dockerfile
    container_name: symfony-container
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./symfony:/var/www/project
    networks:
      - playing

  #mongodb
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo-container
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - '27018:27017'
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db
    networks:
      - playing       

  #angular
  # angular-service:
  #   build:
  #     context: .
  #     dockerfile: ./angular/Dockerfile
  #   container_name: angular-container
  #   command: sh -c "npm start"
  #   ports:
  #     - 4200:4200
  #   working_dir: /home/node/app
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./angular:/home/node/app
  #     - node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
  #   networks:
  #       - playing

volumes:
  mongo:
  node_modules:
```

Comment: try to replace `9000:9000` by `9000:80` and restart the containers